# VS2017 - Solution responds very slow after adding tests project (x-unit)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, xunit

Visual Studio 2017 is almost unusable. It takes so long (sometimes up to 10 minutes) to discover the tests (there are only 50 so its not a huge number of tests) and during this time VS is totally unusable.

My computer is not the problem since this is happening in other computer as well (one is i7 gen 7 and the other is ryzen 5 2600)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is not normal of course.  These two computers have something in common, that helps, you'd look at the installed anti-malware product first.

Comment: There can be many reasons for this. Maybe you have a Resharper, or maybe Live Unit Test is on.

Comment: nope. I don't have Resharper or any anti-malware products installed. Im not on Live Unit Testing either.

Comment: Do you have latest Test.Sdk and xunit runner NuGet packages installed?

Comment: @Fabio Yep I do have the latest versions